# How to insert image before already existing image in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, drop-down-menu

Hi coder i just want to know is this possible to insert an image into database before any other image in the database.

Suppose i have file-up loader to upload image and a drop-down list to show priority of those images.
now i have 10 images in my database and i bind, priority with the drop-down list. Now When i upload new image i can see priority of images into drop-down list. Now that part is been done

Now what i want is when i upload new image and select priority from the drop-down list that image store in the database before the priority of the image in the database.
example:
i select file-up loader button to upload file and select priority number 5 from the drop-down list.
now that image will store at priority number 5 and image which is at priority number 5 now have priority number 6 and so on..

[image]

[image]

How can i do that?

Comment: Can you include the schema for your database table that is storing the image and priority?

Comment: IMO you should not care about the order of the stored images. As long as you stored the correct priority to the image you can then query them in the order you want by append an `ORDER BY priority` clause

Comment: I guess i am not clear to you guys
This is just an example::
suppose i have 50 images in my database with their priority
now if i want to upload new image its priority should be 51 but if i select priority number 30
from the drop-down list then the image that should be uploaded will be 30 and image which
present at 30 move to 31 and so on and image with priority at 50 become 51

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a simple update query using SQL

```
Update table set Priority = Priority + 1 where Priority >= @InputtedPriority
```

You would then need to delete from the database anything over 10

```
DELETE FROM table where Priority > 10
```

**Edit**

Since reading more comments, it just looks like you need to run the first line of SQL to update your table to move the priorities around.  A simple SqlCommand and a stored procedure on the SQL server will fix you right up.  A quick look on SO for executing SqlCommands and procedures shouldn't be too hard to find what you are looking for.

**Edit2**

A simple code example, if you select priority number 30 from the drop-down list and set it to `priority` then the image that should be uploaded will be 30 and image which is present at 30 will move to 31 and so on and image with priority at 50 will become 51. This code assumes ID is a `IDENTIY` column.

```
string imageName; 
string description; 
string path; 
int priority;

//(snip) populate the variables

const string query = "Update imagesTable set Priority = Priority + 1 where Priority >= @Priority;" +
               "insert into imagesTable (ImageName, Description, Path, Priority) values (@ImageName, @Description, @Path, @Priority)";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", imageName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", description);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", path);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", priority);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @AnuragJain he just did, Run the first line he just gave you then perform the insert, that's it. Or do you not know how to run queries in to SQL from C#?

Comment: I wrote up some quick code, mind if I just add it to your question instead of creating 2nd answer saying the same thing?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sure go ahead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain hi soctt in ur code image priority increase but it image didn't add at that particular priority

Comment: It should, it does both the update and the insert in the same command, you would need to add details of any error messages you got if it caused any.

Comment: there is no error it update as well as insert but it will not insert at the selected priority from the dropdown list it will add at the last and update the priority